# JavaScript scope error - returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to understand why my `fullName` variable returns `undefined` in console. It is returning the text from the input in the alert box in the click function. But outside the click function, `fullName` returns `undefined`. Here is the code:

```
var fullName, firstName, middleName, lastName, middleInitials;

$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#nameButton").click(function(event){  // upon clicking the event file
     fullName = $("#name").val().toString();  // that's a jquery function
     alert("fullname" + fullName + ", typeof = " + typeof fullName);  // 20:44 shows correct name
     console.log(typeof fullName); // does not display in console 
    console.log(fullName); // does not display in console
  });

  console.log("fullName = " + fullName);  // 20:44 Shows undefined 

}); // the jquery one
```

Comment: Im pretty sure you'll have an error saying `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined` in your console when you click the button.

Comment: What does `console.log($('#name'))` give? Either execute it in the console, or inside your document.ready function. Perhaps it can't find the element with `id="name"`

Answer (score 4):

When `$(document).ready(function() {` executes the `fullname` variable is `undefined`. When you click the button it will set the variable but by then `$(document).ready(function() {` has already executed...which means `console.log("fullName = " + fullName);` has already executed.

Comment: I redeclared the varialbles after "$(document).ready(function(){", still, the scope of the value of "fullName" remains within the click() button. Can you please explain why? I have never seen this happen before. Will appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @S.Rn the `click()` function is an `event` handler and will only be executed when you click the button...the `$(document).ready` function will be called as soon as the document is ready, which will be before you click the button.

Answer (score 1):

If the element is loaded when the document is ready, you should define the variable before the click happens if you want to see its content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // define the full name here. 
  fullName = $("#name").val().toString();  // that's a jquery function

  $("#nameButton").click(function(event){  // upon clicking the event file
     alert("fullname" + fullName + ", typeof = " + typeof fullName);  // 20:44 shows correct name
     console.log(typeof fullName); // does not display in console 
    console.log(fullName); // does not display in console
  });

  console.log("fullName = " + fullName);  // This should work now. 

});
```